# Difference between adding separate table rows and using rowspan

Tags: jquery, html-table

What is the difference between:

```
jQuery('tr').after('<tr><td rowspan="4">value</td></tr>')
```

and
calling this 4 times

```
jQuery('tr').after('<tr><td>value</td></tr>')
```

I am  trying to change table from

```
  row1  |_____|_______|_______|
  row2  |     |___tr__|_______| 
  row3  |     |       |_______| 
  row4  |_____|_______|_______|
          col1   col2    col3
```

to this:

```
        _______________________
  row1  |_____|_______|_______|
  row2  |     |___tr__|_______| 
  row3  |     |       |       | 
  row4  |_____|_______|_______|
          col1   col2    col3
```

I want to hide row3 and row4, the create a tr that takes 2 rows.

Using jQuery, because I want to change it through a click, it's part of a project

The reason why it does not work for me, is if i use rowspan= n , I need to append n rows at the end to make it work.

Comment: How many columns does your table have? Only one?

Comment: Wouldn't the differences be the same as if you hardcoded the html table with a rowspan or 4 different rows?  What does jQuery have to do with this?

Comment: Is it tabular data, or are you using a table for page layout?

Comment: I am using it for tabular data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `$('tr').after('<tr><td>value</td></tr>')` initiates a new row for each cell when being called four times.

If you wish to have one cell in one row take up the content of four rows, then you would use your first statement.